# Сохранить прокрутку при навигации

Tags: прокрутка

У моего сайта довольно-таки большая шапка сверху, а меню под шапкой. Хотелось бы, чтобы при  переходе по какой-либо ссылке в меню страница прокручивалась вниз, если уже была прокручена на предыдущей странице, и не прокручивалась, если не была. Такое можно сделать?

Проблему я вижу только в том, где лучше всего запомнить положение прокрутки предыдущей страницы.. не в кукис же, и тем более не в бд...

Comment: в get запросе? www.site.com/contacts.html?scroll=1299

Comment: не желательно, у меня и без того адресная строка забита

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сохранить в `window.name` или использовать `localStorage`.

Пример с `window.name`:

```
var ScrollMgr = {
    set: function (x, y) {
        if(arguments.length == 1 && x.y)
        {
            y = x.y; x = x.x;
        }
        window.scrollTo(x, y)
    },
    get: function () {
        return {
            x: window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
            y: window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
        }
    },
    init: function () {
        window.onload = this.restore;
        window.onscroll = this.save;
    },
    save: function () {
        var pos = ScrollMgr.get();
        window.name = pos.x + ',' + pos.y;
    },
    restore: function () {
        var pos = (window.name || '0,0').match(/^(\d+),(\d+)$/);
        if(pos)
            ScrollMgr.set(parseInt(pos[1]), parseInt(pos[2]));
    }
};

ScrollMgr.init();
```

Демо: http://wyto.net/scroll/ (ниже на странице есть ссылка для переходя на следующую)

Comment: то что надо